# How do I solve this BVP?

Tags: integration

I have this set that I would like to solve:

$$ \begin{cases}  y' = 4xe^{2x-y} \\ y(0) = 0 \end{cases} $$

I think that I should integrate the first statement to begin with, but I end up with something odd...

$$ 4\int xe^{2x-y} dx= \{ u = 2x-y, du= 2dx \} = 4\int \frac{1}{2} xe^u du = 2 \int xe^u du= \frac{x^2}{2}e^ {2x-y} $$ The above is my solution but that is not right, acording to Wolfram Alpha, the equation would be (after u substitution): 
$$ 2\int \frac{1}{2}xe^u(u+y) du $$ Why is that, how does the 4 become a 2 and where is the (u+y) from?

Comment: None of this looks sound...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Your problem is to solve the differential equation that is to say to find the expression of $y(x)$ which satisfies $$ y'(x) = 4xe^{2x-y(x)} $$ For sure, this is not the most pleasant form but, suppose you make a change of variable $$y(x)=\log (z(x))$$ The differential equation will just become $$z'(x)=4 e^{2 x} x$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't perform the integration $\int xe^{2x-y}dx$.  $y$ is not just some constant here.

Secondly, if you perform the change of variables you suggested, you get

$$y'=2-u'$$

yielding

$$2-u'=4xe^u$$

which is probably harder than the original equation.  On the other hand, your original equation is separable.  If you multiply both sides by $e^y$, you'll be able to integrate both sides.